# detecting windows shell changes

Tags: delphi, shell, notifications

There is a whole host of components that I am trying out to better understand how to detect when a file or folder has changed. I want to write a delphi application to also do this but  delphi Unicode(Tiburon) doesn't seem to ship with any component that can accomplish this. At least not anymore. I found a curious component on the palette called shellersources and after just placing it on a form and running it I get an error:

> Cmctrls was compiled with a different version of SHLObj.IAutocomplete

I tried virtually all the component listed here: shell resourcehttp://www.torry.net/pages.php?id=252 and interestingly I get the same exact error on compiling them. I am running delphi on Vista, could this be a vista issue? I also tried the SHChangeNotify component from about.com and even it too produced an identical error concerning SHlObj.IAutocomplete. Anyone noticed this? Strange.

Comment: Are you specifying a specific version of ComCtl32.dll?  If so, which?  If not, maybe you should try?

Comment: I am just stating the error that I saw in the IDE. I don't know how to check the version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two Windows API calls that will help you accomplish this in Delphi:

1. [FindFirstChangeNotification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364417(VS.85).aspx)
2. [FindNextChangeNotification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364427(VS.85).aspx)

The drawback is that these function calls are low-level-non-delphi components. But you can still make those function calls in Delphi. If you ABSOLUTELY need a delphi component, you could always write your own, using the mentioned functions as base.

Comment: I have very limited knowledge of using C Builder, could you give me an example or point me to tutorial showing how to use FindNextChangeNotification in Delphi or ,if it is possible, how to use the C component in delphi?